# Module Removed The New Window Option of Link

Tags: module, menu-item

I am using a `SJ Flat` menu module and some of my menu items have the Target windows set to New window with navigation.

Unfortunately, the module removed that attribute and it has a new declaration of the Target behavior.

**Below is the code**

```
$target = "";
$link_target = $params->get('link_target','_self');
switch ($link_target) {
    default:
        case '_self':
        break;
    case '_blank':
    case '_parent':
    case '_top':
        $target = 'target="'.$link_target.'"';
        break;
    case '_windowopen':
        $target = "onclick=\"window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,false');return false;\"";
        break;
    case '_modal':
        // user process
        break;
}
$icon_menu = ($menus[$i]->menu_image != '')
    ? '<img src='.JURI::base().$menus[$i]->menu_image.' alt='.$menus[$i]->title.'  title='.$menus[$i]->title.' />'
    : '';
$divLink = "<div class='fm-link' ".$style.">
        <a ".$target." href='".$menus[$i]->flink."'>".$icon_menu.$menus[$i]->title."</a>
    </div>";
```

Now I want to use the module but will have the natural way of linking.

The situation right now is, I set Target Window to New Window With Navigation in the menu item, see below screencap[image: Target Window]

But the problem is, the target window is being cleared in the module because the module that I am using has a target window setting also. But if you set the target window in the module it will affect all the menu item.

[image: Module Target window setting]

So after checking the codes of the module, I found the above code.

Now I want to disregard the setting in the module and inherit the setting from the menu item

Comment: What does natural way of linking mean - target="_blank"? Or do you know the value?

Comment: I want that whatever is set from the target window from the menu item will be the behavior of the link. The situation right now is, if i set a target from the menu item, it will be removed in the module because the module has an option also to set link target

Answer (score 0):

Target Window to New Window With Navigation = target="_blank"

If you look at:

modules > mod_menu > tmpl > default_url.php

you will find the default Joomla style which is:

```
   if ($item->browserNav == 1)
    {
        $attributes['target'] = '_blank';
    }
    elseif ($item->browserNav == 2)
    {
        $options = 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,' . $params->get('window_open');

        $attributes['onclick'] = "window.open(this.href, 'targetWindow', '" . $options . "'); return false;";
    }
```

Alternatively - the template that you have may have the it located in the following folder:

templates > templatename > html > modules > mod_menu > tmpl > default_url.php

So - looking at these may give you a clue into how to solve it.

Comment: Saw that file and i was trying ti find the right variable, that's where the point i decided to post the problem here

Comment: Are you trying to get a different link for each menu item? Sometimes same window, sometimes new window. Then you would be better off do a menu override.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to achieve. Can you guide me on how to do that?

Comment: Ok - I added a new answer above - it requires a good knowledge of php/html/css and custom templating.

Comment: Thanks for the guide, the good thing is we managed to edit the module files so that it will have the default link behavior

Answer (score 0):

You want to override the menu and give it a unique style for the module position.

A background primer for overrides would be here:
https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides
https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core
https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

So in your template you would create in your html/mod_menu folder - a structure similar to:

https://github.com/thetemplateblog/JoomberUI/tree/master/html/mod_menu

1. Create a new php file that you want to apply the style to: eg: sflat.php
2. Apply the html/php - similar to joomberUI - however with the classes from sflat - as you haven't provided what the final output should be - I can't help you with this.
3. Setup the module, and apply the style sflat